# How to port/use a xib file to cocos2dx

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have a game on iOS and im porting it to android using cocos2dx (c++), is there a way by which i can use the already created xib files? if not, can some one point me on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: no android doesnt use nib(xibs) - 'thats apple tech'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use CocosBuilder and make use of the layer, menu, text and buttons and recreate the UI which can be used in cocos2dx

[Link for cocosbuilder](http://cocosbuilder.com/)